# Creating a live bootable Pen Drive leaves the file system (of the pen drive) as read only

Tags: boot, partitioning, live-usb

I created a live pen drive using the ISO downloaded from www.ubuntu.com. Since the size of the pendrive I have is 64GB, I do not find it convenient to have only the bootable OS in it. I would like to have data files in it too. How do achieve this?

PS: I attempted using GParted, but it really does not help anything. The entire space in the pen drive appears to be locked.

## Ubuntu 16.10 64 bit.